# CentOS Linux shell scripting problem: commands don't seem to be running as expected

Tags: shell, cron

I have a semi-private web server (as in, only people in a certain IP range are allowed to use it, everyone else bar the office is firewalled out), and we changed it to use certificates from Let's Encrypt. The authentication mechanism for this differs to previous paid SSL products and obviously the Let's Encrypt authority must have access to the server during the challenge, and given the short life of LE certificates, that is usually done on a scheduled.

For that reason, I wrote a new Linux shell script to make sure that a revised process would work. Specifically, when first written, the shell script took 4 actions, which I thought were in absolute/hard sequence:

1. Stop the firewall
2. Run the Let's Encrypt Client
3. Restart httpd
4. Start the firewall again.

It used to work fine but earlier this year the process stopped working as expected, specifically that Let's Encrypt client attempts to renew certificates failed and I received email warnings from Let's Encrypt that the cert was about to expire, I think it was because the LE authority could not reach the server (firewall not stopped for some reason). This script is referred to in a Cron job and it is set to output its results into a log file. I've been able to break the job down and do it manually, at one point it even worked running the script myself i.e. when I ran it as opposed to letting cron run it. But it doesn't work automatically.

We use CentOS 7.

Assuming that it might be a time of day thing, I changed the schedule for the script in Cron from early morning to late night, today I found that it ran and renewed the certificate OK, but never restarted httpd. I also looked at the firewall's service and it looked like it had not been restarted for some time either.

Maybe I'm doing something dumb, but it looks like a sequencing problem. I do not have any "hashbangs" in my script. The line of code in Cron that kicks off the process is:

```
30 3 * * * /backup/checklecert.sh > /backup/log/checklecert.txt
```

```
service firehol stop
certbot renew --renew-by-default
service httpd restart
service firehol start
```

The commands should run in sequence (i.e. each command runs, and the system waits for it to finish before going on to the next) and that should make everything work as I expect.

What actually happens is that it looks like only some of the commands in my script run, or that they do not run in strict sequence.

Edit: looks like my code was not included with the question. The code used in the cron file to kick off the process is:

```
10 20 * * 1 /backup/checklecert.sh > /backup/log/checklecert.txt
```

The code file for "checklecert.sh" is:

```
service firehol stop
certbot renew --renew-by-default
service httpd restart
service firehol start
```

Comment: Does the script not have a shebang? Doesn’t that confuse cron?

Comment: No, it does not have a shebang. Would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

The https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/6379 --renew-by-default option is discouraged.  I would recommend the shebang, cron daemon should set a shell variable by default though.

Comment: Thanks tDarkCrystal. I'll try adding a shebang and see if that works, didn't even know what that was until today :} When it was working properly I just used used renew, but added a force-renew so that I could test changes. I fully intend to get rid of it when I have everything working again.